Error opening a file from a network Share
Really weird behavior opening a file.
I'm getting an error message trying to open a .sql file.
If I'm in SSMS, I get this error message:
"The operation could not be completed. The parameter is incorrect."
If I'm Using Teradata Studio I get this error message:
"The file 'xxx.sql' could not be found.
If I right_click on the file and try to open it with or Edit with Notepad++, the text editor will open but it won't open the file. However, I can open Notepad++ and navigate to the file and open it.
Anyone else seen this???
